# ios how to rotate control 360 degree

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, uiview, rotation

I want to rotate control over 360 degrees. I do it like that right now

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    [self.crossButton setTransform:CGAffineTransformRotate(self.crossButton.transform, degreesToRadians(360))];
} completion:nil];
```

But nothings happens. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A rotation transformation by 360 degrees is the identity transformation, therefore the
object is not animated at all.

You can achieve the desired effect with a "basic property animation":

```
[CATransaction begin];
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.byValue = @(2 * M_PI); // 360 degrees
rotationAnimation.duration = 0.25;
rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
[self.crossButton.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

*Update:* If the rotation amount is not 360 degrees (so that the final position is not the same
as the initial position) then the following should work:

```
[CATransaction begin];
CGFloat angle = 45.0 * M_PI/180.0;
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation;
rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotationAnimation.byValue = @(angle);
rotationAnimation.duration = 0.25;
rotationAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
rotationAnimation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    self.crossButton.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.button.transform, angle);
}];
[self.crossButton.layer addAnimation:rotationAnimation forKey:@"rotationAnimation"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: But when I rotate it by 45 degree its has a nasty jump to 90 degree

Answer (score 1):

If you are rotating for 360 degree, you are putting the object back into same position. If you want to see animation, increase the delay and check. You will find entire object to move for a perfect circle.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{

        self.crossButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);

    } completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3:**

Using **CABasicAnimation**

```
var rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation()
rotationAnimation = CABasicAnimation.init(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
rotationAnimation.toValue = NSNumber(value: (Double.pi * 2.0))
rotationAnimation.duration = 1.0
rotationAnimation.isCumulative = true
rotationAnimation.repeatCount = 100.0
view.layer.add(rotationAnimation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
```

Here is an extension functions for UIView that handles start & stop rotation operations:

```
extension UIView {

    func startRotation() {
        let rotation : CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
        rotation.fromValue = 0
        rotation.toValue = NSNumber(value: Double.pi * 2.0)
        rotation.duration = 1.0
        rotation.isCumulative = true
        rotation.repeatCount = FLT_MAX
        self.layer.add(rotation, forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }

    func stopRotation() {
        self.layer.removeAnimation(forKey: "rotationAnimation")
    }
}
```

Now using, UIView.animation closure:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { 
      button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(Double.pi)) 
}) { (isHalfAnimationComplete) in
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { 
       button.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(Double.pi * 2))
    }    
}
```